# How to use extension like glGenBuffersARB in Qt5?

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5, opengl-extensions, qopenglfunctions

I am trying desperately to understand the architecture of **OpenGL** support in **Qt5**.

My current problem is this: I have some existing OpenGL code (desktop, *not OpenGL ES*) that uses some OpenGL extensions, including `glGenBuffersARB`. Outside Qt5 getting access to the functions for extensions like this is trivial, for example by using **GLEW** I could simply do this:

```
glewInit();
```

And everything would just magically work as expected, and I could start to use `glGenBuffersARB` straight away. If I was ever worried, I could throw in a call to `glewIsSupported` to be sure it was supported.

But in Qt5 there is a warning that GLEW and `QOpenGLFunctions` don't play well together (copied from `qopenglfunctions.h`):

```
#ifdef __GLEW_H__
#if defined(Q_CC_GNU)
#warning qopenglfunctions.h is not compatible with GLEW, GLEW defines will be undefined
#warning To use GLEW with Qt, do not include <qopengl.h> or <QOpenGLFunctions> after glew.h
#endif
#endif
```

So let's say that I for the sake of this question and to satisfy the curiosity ditch GLEW completely and rely solely on Qt5 for a pure Qt5 approach. How would I get my existing OpenGL code that relies on glGenBuffersARB to work without manually binding each and every extension function manually?

NOTE: I know I can follow tips in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865864/qopenglfunctions-missing-important-opengl-functions) answer and do this:

```
auto functions = context->versionFunctions<QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core>();
if (!functions) error();
functions->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
functions->glGenBuffersARB(...);
```

But then I would have to prefix every single line of existing OpenGL code with `functions->` which I would rather not do.

Comment: FYI: Don't ever use `glGenBuffersARB`. `glGenBuffers` has been core OpenGL for nearly *fifteen years*.

Comment: I just realized that, sorry it was a really bad example, but I think the question is still good. Just imagine I was talking about another extension that is relevant today! (that is the extension that my existing OpenGL code uses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to have GL functions be available to the class in Qt5, without needing to use a helper, is to make your GL class derive from a subclass of [QAbstractOpenGLFunctions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractopenglfunctions.html). For example your header file might look something like this:

```
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_1_1>
class MyGLClass : protected QOpenGLFunctions_1_1
{
    ...
}
```

Then in your initialize method you need to initialize
the OpenGL functions like so:

```
void MyGLClass::initialize()
{
    if (!initializeOpenGLFunctions()) {
        qFatal("initializeOpenGLFunctions failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> But then I would have to prefix every single line of existing OpenGL code with `functions->` which I would rather not do.

You could of course use `QOpenGLContext::getProcAddress` to load the function pointers yourself. But the only interface that Qt provides that handles function loading for you is the `QOpenGLFunctions_*` one. Not only that, they don't really cover extensions.

You could use Qt's OpenGL wrapper classes like `QOpenGLBuffer` and so forth. But those are a lowest-common-denominator sort of thing. They don't wrap everything you could do with buffers using modern OpenGL. And again, they don't cover *extensions*; only stuff that's core functionality.

And there's plenty of OpenGL not wrapped by such objects, so it's not exactly a comprehensive solution.

Better to stick with a proper [OpenGL Loading Library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: It's technically incorrect to say that wrappers `QOpenGLBuffer` is a lowest-common-denominator. While not supporting *all* the possible buffer object features, it actually checks for extensions, so for instance it supports ranged maps. (Then, it also has other fundamental problems). QOpenGLTexture supports immutable storage, texture views and similar.

Comment: About extensions, there's actually the QtOpenGLExtensions library (`QT += openglextensions`), that you can use just like `QOpenGLFunctions`. Like `auto f = new QOpenGLExtension_KHR_debug; f->initializeOpenGLFunctions(); f->glDebugMessage...`. I've no idea why it's not documented, likely a bug (since it's autogenerated).